# Choose k not-adjacent elements out of N

Tags: combinations

Suppose we have a line of dots, there are totally N of them, we are to choose k dots such that each pairs of dots are not neighbors. How many possibilities there are in total?

For example, if we have N = 3 dots, we want to choose 2 dots that aren't adjacent, then there's only 1 possibility.

Comment: Please don't post math problems on Stack Overflow. This site is meant for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

First and last dots have `N-2` options to choose from, as you can't select the same dot or its neighbor. All the other 'inside' dots have `N-3` options, as you can't select the same and one adjacent dot on each side.

If you would sum them all up, you would get twice as many options (because of duplicates). So `N-2` dots have `N-3` options, but you have to divide it by 2.

The result would be `K = (N-2) + (N-2)*(N-3)/2`